# MySQL's innodb_buffer_pool_size doesn't seem to have any effect on RAM usage

Tags: mysql, memory-usage, innodb, mysql5

(I have checked similar questions, none of them cover my situation)

I'm trying to increase MySQL 5.7 memory usage on my Ubuntu 16.04. Before my changes `mysqld` was using about 8% of RAM out of 8GB available which means the InnoDB buffer pool was probably set to 512MB.

I set `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to 4G, I restart `mysqld`, then I check the `@@innodb_buffer_pool_size` variable: it shows `4294967296` which is correct.

However `top` is telling me that the memory usage is still at 8%! I have some pretty large tables with millions of records, I run heavy queries but no matter what, `mysqld` never seems to go over 8%. And yes, all my tables use InnoDB.

I tried to also play with `innodb_buffer_pool_instances` and `innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size` but again, the changes are reflected in the @@ variables but nothing makes `mysqld` go over 8%, so I reverted these two variables to their defaults.

Every article or SO answer on the subject says that changing `innodb_buffer_pool_size` and restarting MySQL should be sufficient. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe MySQL just hasn't put a large amount of data in the buffer pool yet? Check with `SHOW STATUS WHERE Variable_name = 'Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data';`

Comment: @MichaelHampton it currently shows `625442816`. What does it mean though, does mysql grow the buffers gradually? Even despite that the server is already under high load? That's a bit odd.

Comment: If that's your entire working set, then you don't really need much more memory than that, no matter how many queries per second you have.

Comment: @MichaelHampton that might be true actually. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
for server workload tuning analysis.